# Problema de conexión a SQL Server con Laravel

Tags: laravel

En esta ocasión mi aplicación basada en Laravel 5.6 debe consumir información de una base de datos SQL Server, pero me arroja un error de conexión.
Aquí la configuración de mi aplicación

**ENV**

```
DB_CONNECTION=pip1
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=WebSLFC
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=sql
```

**Database.php**

```
'pip1' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), 
        ]
```

**La consulta de BD desde mi Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = DB::connection('pip1')->select("EXEC inia_getSubProyectos @codRegion='',@codEEA= 0, @codCadena =0");
    return view('app.reporteCultivo', compact('data'));
}
```

Cabe resaltar que mi aplicación esta en homestead por lo que mi máquina virtual esta con ubuntu.

**Error que me imprime**

"SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (SQL: EXEC inia_getSubProyectos @codRegion='',@codEEA= 0, @codCadena =0)"

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta configuración, espero que te ayude.

**.ENV**

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=MY_sERVER\SQLEXPRESS
DB_DATABASE=my_db
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```

**config/database.php**

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', null),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],
```

**CONSULTA**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
DB::statement('EXECUTE sp_sm_U_sistemastiposplan ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?',
                [
                    null,
                    $request->codigoSistema,
                    $request -> codigoTipoPlan[$i],
                    1,
                    $request -> formatos[$i],
                    Auth::user()->id,
                    null,
                    null,
                    Auth::user()->id,
                ]);
}
```

Comment: Prueba esta configuración, espero que te ayude.